# Any way to trick denied remote access MySQL database?

Tags: c#, mysql, cpanel

So i purchased a host on NoPayHost.com. But they dont allow to use remote mysql connection.
I wanted to make a client application in C#. And once in a while it would do some insert and selects. Now this option is down. Is there any way to trick this? There is running webserver, ftp server and something more ( you can look at that site ). I though, maybe its possible to send some data directly to webserver, and then parse my data with php or something.. ?? I dont know, havent don anyting like this before.
edit:
Maybe one way would be to send data as POST? Could i get it to work ?

heh, did it

```
public class PostRequest
{
    private WebRequest request;
    private Stream dataStream;
    public PostRequest(string url, string data)
    {
        request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        string postData = data;
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
    }

    public string GetResponse()
    {
        string responseFromServer = new StreamReader(
            request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        dataStream.Close();
        return responseFromServer;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PostRequest myRequest = new PostRequest(
        "http://www.domain.net", "a=value1&b=value2");
    Console.WriteLine(myRequest.GetResponse());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to install phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

You mean, like a service oriented approach? You can encapsulate these requirements into web services which expose the data and/or functionality (like inserting data), but don't forget to add security to the list of thinks to implement. Which technology to choose depends on your webserver.

Comment: i dont realy know what i ment :D hoped to get some links to examples. :x

Answer (score 0):

You could create a webservice (or web app) that handles the database hits and returns a dataset back to the application.   then as far as mysql is concerned, the hits are coming from the local webserver.